# Clearing an invalidated quest from the journal (Mark as complete)

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

So... Long story short, I killed Melka. I got frustrated because the gate said `Press E to Open Gate` and it simply would not. I gave up at the time (several actual days ago) and am just now going through my `Miscellaneous` quests to clean them out of my log. Today I walked up and saw, oh... there's a chain there. I opened the chain, and there was the body.

Well apparently murdering her didn't invalidate the quest and now it's still in my log as `Kill the Hagraven Petra`. I'm on PC and honestly just want to get it out of my log. I consider the quest "complete" as my goal was to get a staff and after looting the body, uh mission accomplished. I'm fairly confident that this quest was purely optional (and that I took a valid course of action to complete it).

Is there a console command to complete a quest (or mark it as complete) or any other way of removing it from my log?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Or.. to get the quest off the books, bring console up with <kbd>~</kbd> (Tilde), type "setstage dunBlindCliffQST 100" and this finishes the quest and sets it as completed.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks a bunch, but honestly, could you provide a little more explanation? How on earth did that complete my quest? Is there  an index of quest names to reference?

Comment: Quests in Elder Scrolls are managed by "stages". Each quest (with an internal name such as dunBlindCliffQST) has a bunch of numbers associated to each stage of the quest, where 0 is usually "not started" and 100 is usually "finished", with maybe 105 or similar for alternate endings.
I believe there's a list of internal names at the UESP (can't link from here, work blocks the page).

Comment: Doesn't using console commands prevent you from getting any more achievements?

Comment: @BlueRaja: **NO** using the console **does not** disable Steam achievements in Skyrim. I have no idea where that rumor originated, but it seems to be surprisingly widespread...

Comment: @BlueRaja I have recieved several achievements since using this **fix**. The game broke, I used the console to fix it.

Comment: @Dave Thanks, appears I was wrong: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/37694/do-console-commands-affect-steam-achievements

Answer (score 1):

Press <kbd>~</kbd> (Tilde) to bring up the console, click on the body and type `Resurrect`. You should be able to continue the quest.

Comment: `resurrect 1` is a safer option, from what I've heard.  Less chance of erratic behavior.  (The `1` causes the actor to simply stand back up rather than disabling/enabling them; avoids some kind of internal reset.)

Comment: I actually tried both of these and she came back, but I was unable to speak or complete the quest. Possibly because I already took the staff from the body?