# Is it possible to complete Daedric Artefact Achivement without killing Silus?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

First time I took Mehrune's Razor, but then I reload and save Silus. Also, I thought Skeleton Key counting as artifact too.

Now I can't get ahievment. I lost all saves near this quest point, also I almost complete other quest lines for now, so it is painfull to start this game one more time for 15 questlines. So I want to know is there are the way to get this achivement? Maybe console that will reset quest and do not affect ahivement system (as I heard, some console commands can be count as cheat and ahivement system will be blocked)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't know if this answer helps you at this point but I will put this here anyway in case it helps someone else. You can still get the achievement even after missing one artifact if you meet the following conditions:

1. You haven't already completed the quest Ill met by Moonlight (Daedric prince Hircine quest).
2. You have missed only ONE artifact up to this point, which in your case seems to be the Mehrune's Razor.

In the quest Ill met by Moonlight, it is possible to get both Daedric artifacts and have them both count towards your total. You will be asked by Hircine at one point in the quest to kill Sinding. When you enter the cave, speak to Sinding, and help him kill the other hunters first. Then exit the cave and you will find Hircine waiting for you and he will give you the (restored) Ring of Hircine. Then go back inside the cave, find Sinding and kill him. Hircine should appear again and give you the Savior's Hide.

This extra artifact makes up for the missed artifact above and counts towards the total of 15 artifacts you need towards your achievement and provided you get all the remaining artifacts you should get the achievement. I am sure this works since I did this on my ps3 after missing another artifact like you did. I got the trophy.

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Yes it works and seems that is legal way to get achivement.

Comment: One tip: you can complete this quest and still when you return to the cave warewolf will be there and you will be able to complete quest.

Comment: Is that how you did it? I read somewhere that Siding can be spotted sometimes roaming around Skyrim after this quest, so i assumed he doesn't stay in the cave for long.

Comment: Well, yes. But there wasn't a lot of time before my returning: I complete 1-2 more Daedric quests and then return to him. Maybe after a year in game he will leave cave.

Answer (score 1):

No, I've tried to console my way to the achievement by adding 15 artifacts into my inventory before, it doesn't work.  I'm afraid it actually keeps track via quest status somehow.  And since you can't use the console on an completed quest, I'm afraid you are out of luck.

As for console use preventing achievements, [this has been proven false](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/37694/do-console-commands-affect-steam-achievements).

Comment: Well, this link is my savior then. I have no other way to start game one more time or load it from latest saves and then use cheats to fullfill items and levels to go throught all daedric quests one more time.