# Can I continue to earn achievements if I install mods from Skyrim SE's Creation Club?

Tags: achievements, the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I've been replaying Skyrim Special Edition for a little while now and I would like to spice things up by installing some mods from Bethesda's Creation Club.

On the Xbox One would I be prohibited from earning achievements if I added mods to my game? I've read that [using Skyrim's console commands](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/37694/do-console-commands-affect-steam-achievements/39159#39159) does not prohibit the acquisition of Steam achievements but I don't know if comparing Creation Club mods to console commands is like comparing apples to oranges.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The previous answer did not accurately answer the question asked. [Creation Club addons do not disable achievements](https://help.bethesda.net/app/answers/detail/a_id/39862/~/does-using-the-creation-club-disable-achievements-%2F-trophies%3F), as they are official Bethesda-endorsed mods that are considered to be more of a DLC, since you have to buy them. If you use actual mods, however, it will disable achievements.

Comment: Does this mean the statement "Creation Club content is not a mod" is accurate?

Comment: @PausePause Technically no. Well, a mod is a modification, so in that sense additional objects or quests can be considered add-ons, or just 'content'. But almost all mods are 'content', too. Some refer to Creation Club content as 'Creations', which, technically, all mods are, as well. But the Creation Club content has a few modifications as well (like their '[Camping](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Camping)' ..thing, which undoubtedly modifies certain game assets). Semantics. Probably Bethesda's attempt to disguise their abhorrent achievement-block.

Comment: Would starting a clean save make achievements available again? Or should they be stripped away from the game completely?

Comment: @pingqueen I'm not sure what you mean, but if you disable your mods before starting a new save, the new save will indeed have achievements enabled again.

Comment: @joachim The main reason Bethesda chose to begin the Creation Club was to allow modding on the PlayStation to advance a little further. Due to Sony's restrictions, the mods from the mod menu cannot contain any external assets that are not already part of te game. You can slightly alter the models of some things to make them look different, but cannot implement a brand new model that doesn't exist elsewhere. The Creation Club bypasses this by making certain mods official DLC content, which means that any mod with external assets that Bethesda likes can be played on ps4.

Comment: And strictly speaking, the Creation Club packs cost money, so are much closer to a DLC than typical mods.

Comment: Oh yeah, in addition, the Creation Club items actually do add new models and scripts, which are then available for traditional mods to tweak for their own uses.